Need to get specific value from an URL with sed or awk
from 2 different urls, I want to get only a specific value with sed or awk commands
Here are the urls from variables :
normal="https://example.com/techsol-devops/slr-devops/-/pipelines/10112283"
dedicated="https://example.com/ims/techsol-devops/oa/oa-tenants/slr-devops/-/pipelines/3359684"

From those variables, I want to get the below values with one command (sed or awk) :
example.com/techsol-devops
OR
example.com/ims/techsol-devops
I have already tested this kind of sed command, but it's working ONLY for the "dedicated" variable, not for "normal" variable !
sed -E 's|https://([^/]+/[^/]+/techsol-devops).*|\1|'

The goal is to get the value between "https://" and "techsol-devops" included
Thanks for your help on this topic

I found a solution with the following sed command :
echo $normal | sed -E 's|https://||' | sed -E 's|(.techsol-devops).|\1|'
It's working for the "dedicated" variable as well, but now, I would like to get the same result if techsol-devops can be techsol-prodops also

Try sed 's,^https\?://,,;s,\(/techsol-devops\)/.*$,\1,'

A more accurate approach would be to use a tool, that is URI syntax aware, e.g. in python or perl

Regarding "but now, I would like to get the same result if techsol-devops can be techsol-prodops also" - don't add information in comments where it can't be formatted and could be missed. Make sure your question contains all relevant information.

How about this : sed -E -e 's%^https://([a-z./]+/techsol-(dev|prod)ops)/.+%\1%'

Try bash regexp:
reg='https://.*/techsol-devops'

[[ $normal =~ $reg ]] && echo $BASH_REMATCH
https://example.com/techsol-devops

$ [[ $dedicated =~ $reg ]] && echo $BASH_REMATCH
https://example.com/ims/techsol-devops


Thanks for your help, but I don't want to get the "https://" value, and in the meanwhile, I would like to filter on techsol-prodops or techsol-ProdOps in addition to techsol-devops

Thanks for your code, I found my solution.
reg='https://.*/(techsol-(devops|[Pp]rod[Oo]ps))'
[[ ${CI_PIPELINE_URL} =~ $reg ]] && echo $BASH_REMATCH | awk -F'//' '{print $2}'

$BASH_REMATCH is actually an array with all matches, if you need to remove "https://" just add one more group to regexp like this reg='https://(.*/(techsol-(devops|[Pp]rod[Oo]ps)))' and you'll get the result without any external commands like this: [[ $normal =~ $reg ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}


get the value between "https://" and "techsol-devops" included

I would use GNU AWK for this task following way
normal="https://example.com/techsol-devops/slr-devops/-/pipelines/10112283"
dedicated="https://example.com/ims/techsol-devops/oa/oa-tenants/slr-devops/-/pipelines/3359684"
normalcore=$(echo "$normal" | awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="https://.*techsol-devops"}$1{print substr($1,9)}')
dedicatedcore=$(echo "$dedicated" | awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="https://.*techsol-devops"}$1{print substr($1,9)}')
echo "$normalcore"
echo "$dedicatedcore"

gives output
example.com/techsol-devops
example.com/ims/techsol-devops

Explanation: I use FPAT built-in variable to inform GNU AWK that field constitute https:// followed by zero-or-more (*) any character (.) followed by techsol-devops, then if there is non-empty 1st field in line I print substring of 1st field starting at 9th character in order to jettison https://. Keep in mind in this solution assumes that you have 1 or less address to process in each bash variable.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.3.1)

This will do what you want as long as techsol-devops can't appear in other, undesirable parts of the URL:
$ [[ "$normal" =~ ^https://(.*/techsol-devops)(/|$) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
example.com/techsol-devops
$ [[ "$dedicated" =~ ^https://(.*/techsol-devops)(/|$) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
example.com/ims/techsol-devops

It's always easier to match the text you want than to not match similar text you don't want so the (/|$) at the end of the regexp is to avoid matching on https://example.com/techsol-devopsonic or similar.
To also do what you said you want in a comment:

but now, I would like to get the same result if techsol-devops can be
techsol-prodops also

You can just tweak the regexp above to
^https://(.*/techsol-(dev|prod)ops)(/|$)

